# 32-1024 bit fixed point vector arithmetic with AVX-2

Tags: biginteger, avx, fixed-point, avx2

For a mandelbrot generator I want to used fixed point arithmetic going from 32 up to maybe 1024 bit as you zoom in.

Now normaly SSE or AVX is no help there due to the lack of add with carry and doing normal integer arithmetic is faster. But in my case I have literally millions of pixels that all need to be computed. So I have a huge vector of values that all need to go through the same iterative formula over and over a million times too.

So I'm not looking at doing a fixed point add/sub/mul on single values but doing it on huge vectors. My hope is that for such vector operations AVX/AVX2 can still be utilized to improve the performance despite the lack of native add with carry.

Anyone know of a library for fixed point arithmetic on vectors or some example code how to do emulate add with carry on AVX/AVX2.

Answer (score 0):

FP extended precision gives more bits per clock cycle (because `double` FMA throughput is 2/clock vs. 32x32=>64-bit at 1 or 2/clock on Intel CPUs); consider using the same tricks that Prime95 uses with FMA for integer math.  With care it's possible to use FPU hardware for bit-exact integer work.

---

For your actual question: since you want to do the same thing to multiple pixels in parallel, probably you want to do carries between corresponding elements in separate vectors, so one `__m256i` holds 64-bit chunks of 4 separate bigintegers, not 4 chunks of the same integer.

Register pressure is a problem for very wide integers with this strategy.  Perhaps you can usefully branch on there being no carry propagation past the 4th or 6th vector of chunks, or something, by using `vpmovmskb` on the compare result to generate the carry-out after each add.  An unsigned add has carry out of `a+b < a` (unsigned compare)

But AVX2 only has signed integer compares (for greater-than), not unsigned.   And with carry-in, `(a+b+c_in) == a` is possible with b=carry_in=0 or with b=0xFFF... and carry_in=1 so generating carry-out is not simple.

To solve both those problems, consider using chunks with manual wrapping to 60-bit or 62-bit or something, so they're guaranteed to be signed-positive and so carry-out from addition appears in the high bits of the full 64-bit element.  (Where you can `vpsrlq ymm, 62` to extract it for addition into the vector of next higher chunks.)

Maybe even 63-bit chunks would work here so carry appears in the very top bit, and `vmovmskpd` can check if any element produced a carry.  Otherwise `vptest` can do that with the right mask.

---

This is a handy-wavy kind of brainstorm answer; I don't have any plans to expand it into a detailed answer.  If anyone wants to write actual code based on this, please post your own answer so we can upvote that (if it turns out to be a useful idea at all).

Comment: I indeed thought about using 64-bit chunks of 4 separate bigintegers. You have to do a ripple carry so 4 chunks of the same integer wouldn't parallelize.

Comment: Small and medium-sized bignums suck on SIMD. They suck slightly less with AVX512-IFMA, but they still suck. Nothing good until you get into FFT land.

Comment: @Mysticial: Hmm yeah, add and sub look like break-even with AVX2 for *multiple* bignums in parallel.  Needing manual carry propagation makes the cost per addition probably 2x `vpaddq` (a+b+carry) + `vpsrlq` (generate carry-out) + `vpand` (clear the carry-out from the original). But that only gives you at most 63 bits per limb vs. single-uop `adc` for 64 bits per uop.  Interleaving scalar dep chains with adc lets OoO exec interleave.  With AVX512 you're getting twice as much work per vector, but 4/clock `adc` vs. 2/clock 512-bit vector stuff hurts. Still, register pressure is a thing for scalar

Comment: And that's the best case.  Multiply is horrible vs. scalar, where `mul` or `mulx` produces 128 product bits per cycle with a single uop, leaving other back-end bandwidth free for the `adc` parts.

Comment: The (nasty) trick is to take the partial-word representation thing to the extreme. Rather than the 60 or the 62 that you suggest, you go all the way down to something *below* 52 bits and put everything in DP-floats. Then you can abuse the FMA hardware to efficiently grab the entire result of a "word-sized multiply". Going below 52 bits will allow you to ignore/defer carryout on additions+subtractions including those that are needed inside a large multiply. AVX512-IFMA lets you stay on the integer side with exactly 52 bit words as you can now use the entire 64-bit integer for overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Just for kicks, without claiming that this will be actually useful, you can extract the carry bit of an addition by just looking at the upper bits of the input and output values.

```
unsigned result = a + b + last_carry;  // add a, b and (optionally last carry)

unsigned carry = (a & b)  // carry if both a AND b have the upper bit set
                 |        // OR
                 ((a ^ b) // upper bits of a and b are different AND
                  & ~r);  // AND upper bit of the result is not set
carry >>= sizeof(unsigned)*8 - 1; // shift the upper bit to the lower bit
```

With SSE2/AVX2 this could be implemented with two additions, 4 logic operations and one shift, but works for arbitrary (supported) integer sizes (uint8, uint16, uint32, uint64). With AVX2 you'd need 7uops to get 4 64bit additions with carry-in and carry-out.

Especially since multiplying `64x64-->128` is not possible either (but would require 4 `32x32-->64` products -- and some additions or 3 `32x32-->64` products and even more additions, as well as special case handling), you will likely not be more efficient than with `mul` and `adc` (maybe unless register pressure is your bottleneck).As

As Peter and Mystical suggested, working with smaller limbs (still stored in 64 bits) can be beneficial. On the one hand, with some trickery, you can use FMA for `52x52-->104` products. And also, you can actually add up to 2^k-1 numbers of 64-k bits before you need to carry the upper bits of the previous limbs.